# Custom Item Reader that uses JdbcPagingItemReader?

Tags: java, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

I am able to read from my db when this code snippet is in my batchConfig

```
 @Bean
public ItemReader<? extends Orders> reader() {

    JdbcPagingItemReader<Orders> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<Orders>();
    final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select *");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause("from orders");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause(
        "where order_status=var1 and date < var2");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey("date");

    try {
        reader.setQueryProvider(sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setPageSize(3);
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Orders>(Orders.class));
    return reader;
}
```

However, I am not able to pass variables to this ItemReader dynamically from my Restful API. From what I read, I should create a custom item reader however I am not sure how to create that leveraging JdbcPagingItemReader.

Would any of you help me on this one? Thanks!

```
public void orderProcess(String var1) {
        taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                        .addString("var1", var1)
                        .addString("var", "sampleValue1")
                        .addString("time",
                            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
                                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))
                        .addDate("date", new Date()).toJobParameters();
                    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LogUtil.logError(LOGGER, "ERROR IN STARTING JOB", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: your code is missing a ". You do understand that this is already a custom reader, right? Just because you are using existing classes, doesn't mean the whole is not customized to your needs

Comment: Hi @Stultuske thanks for pointing out the missing ". I am not very familiar with Spring Batch but what I am trying to do is to supply the var1 and var2 in the query dynamically.

Comment: How are these `var1` and `var2` passed to your job from the Resful API? Are they retrieved before the job is launched and passed to the job as parameters? Please share the code of where these variables are taken from to understand the dynamism you have and give you the correct answer. You basically need a step-scoped item reader, and the way to do that depends on your answer to the previous question.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, i want to pass it using job parameters, i added in the question

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, i want to pass it using job parameters, i added in the question

In that case, you should make your item reader step-scoped in order to inject job parameters in its configuration dynamically. Here is an example:

```
 @Bean
public ItemReader<? extends Orders> reader(
                    @Value("#{jobParameters['var1']}") String var1,
                    @Value("#{jobParameters['var2']}") String var2) {

    JdbcPagingItemReader<Orders> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<Orders>();
    final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select *");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause("from orders");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause(
        "where order_status=" + var1 + " and date < " + var2);
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey("date");

    try {
        reader.setQueryProvider(sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setPageSize(3);
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Orders>(Orders.class));
    return reader;
}
```

You can find more details in the reference documentation here: [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding)